# Schema design for a geocoding table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hash

I'm thinking to cache a list of addresses and their coordinates (lat + long) in SQL Server. Usually I get the coordinates by invoking a web service and in order to avoid a round trip to that WS I want to store all those WS responses in a local SQL Server database.

I'm wondering how to optimally store WS responses in my local SQL Server database as I might have a list of 500k addresses? I was thinking to the following structure:

```
AddressHash BIGINT -- PK, clustered index, 
--obtained by applying a hashing algorith (SHA-1?) of
--Street|StreetNumber|Zip|City|County|Country
Lat DECIMAL 
Long DECIMAL
```

1/ What do you think about?

2/ Do you recommend a better(=faster) hashing algorithm?

3/ BIGINT is an optimal datatype in this case?

4/ Do you any other optimal way to store those data in SQL Server?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Can you describe the common data access pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If only there were a dedicated data type for storing geographic data... oh wait, there is

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx

Comment: geography datatype won't be of much help with geocodes. reverse geocodes + spatial index, yes.

Comment: Why wouldn't geography be a good fit for this? You're going to ask this table "given this address, where on the globe is it?" and a geography point is an appropriate answer.

Comment: A geography point takes 22 bytes, Long and Lat DEC(9,6) takes 5 bytes each, so saving storage. Also the cost of converting long and lat to geography during the insert... then the cost of converting back from geography to long and lat. the biggest benefit of geography datatype is access to their spatial functions and indexes. geocoding doens't need any of that. If the table will be used for other purposes that need these spatial functions and indexes, eg reverse geocoding, then sure.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the bigint question, use whatever data type the hashbytes function returns.